# Take a screenshot of app then attach in Message using Swift

Tags: swift, screenshot, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to take a screenshot of my app then send it to a contact in a message.  The screenshot is taken just fine when I view it in my Photo Library... but when the message composer opens the image it appears with "?" like the mime type isn't correct.  I am converting the image to NSData with UIImageJPEGRepresentation.  What am I doing wrong?  Many thanks

```
func screenShotMethod() {


    if (messageComposer.canSendText()) {
        // Obtain a configured MFMessageComposeViewController
         //Create the UIImage
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)

        view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        //Save it to the camera roll
        //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

        let messageComposeVC = messageComposer.configuredMessageComposeViewController()
        //messageComposeVC.body = image
        var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
        messageComposeVC.addAttachmentData(imageData, typeIdentifier: "image/jpeg", filename: "My Image")
        presentViewController(messageComposeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        println("No good")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I figured out the issue myself.  The filename needs an extension.  I added ".jpeg" like so:

```
    messageComposeVC.addAttachmentData(imageData, typeIdentifier: "image/jpeg", filename: "My Image.jpeg")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
controller.addAttachmentData(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(screenShot, CGFloat(1.0))!, typeIdentifier: "image/jpeg", filename: "test.jpg")
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain your code and explain why it is better than the already existing answer posted 1 year ago...